# Problem in launching new emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Emulator is not starting showing “ invalid command-line parameter”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter)

when I try to launch a new emulator it shows like this

[2011-07-19 22:47:34 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: and.
[2011-07-19 22:47:34 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-19 22:47:34 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

anybody plz help me out.

Comment: This has already been answered so many times. One of them is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492676/invalid-command-line-parameter-when-android-execution

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter

Answer (score 0):

My fix for this issue was to take the android folder out of program files and move it to the C drive (or where ever you installed windows). (I had a 64 bit system and for some reason android installed to the x86 program files location) Did this fix your error?

Answer (score 0):

The path of your android-sdk contains spaces like if you put in Program Files,there is a space between program and files.So remove this or simply do as coop said.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK path can't contain space. It is the problem.