# Unable to start the Android Virtual AVD device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk, android-manifest

I have successfully installed the Android SDK and also linked the SDK Manager to the SDK path. Then I have created the AVD of API 8 and it's done.
But while I am going to start the Virtual Device it's not started and gives me error like `"@foo" can not started, commend line error`, and also give me hint: `open @foo for virtual device`.

What exactly is 'foo'?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920816/error-android-sdk-invalid-command-line-parameter-files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492676/invalid-command-line-parameter-when-android-execution

Comment: Ok. I got the Sollution. Thanks For the Answers and links.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces may be contained in the installation path of Android SDK.

You may move it under a path with no space in it.