# Error While Launching the Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have been working on an application, which was running absolutely fine before i switched to another application. After few days when i came to work on my previous application, I am getting this particular error while launching the emulator for it. This error is as follows:

```
[2011-08-24 11:46:06 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: partition-size 1024.
[2011-08-24 11:46:06 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-08-24 11:46:06 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

What could possibly be the issue..??? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces may be contained in the installation path of Android SDK.

You may move it under a path with no space in it.

[unable-to-start-the-android-virtual-avd-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156463/unable-to-start-the-android-virtual-avd-device/7156528#7156528)

Comment: This really was a little but extremely teasing one, but i got the answer myself.

"Just got to eclipse > open android sdk and avd manager > select the required avd > start and  check the wipe userdata box."

This worked for me, hope this works for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

change the path of the SDK. put SDK directly in the drive ie. **"d:\Android\android-sdk-tools"**

note: make sure that there is no space in parent path

Answer (score 0):

This really was a little but extremely teasing one, but i got the answer myself.

Just got to eclipse > open android sdk and avd manager > select the required avd > start and check the wipe userdata box.

This worked for me, hope this works for others as well...:-)