# In Eclipse.. How to adjust the path of Android SDK folder?

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, android-emulator, command-line-arguments, android-sdk-tools

First of all, I'm a total newbie to all of this stuff and I was pushed into it.

Acording to these two topics:
[Starting the Android emulator in SDK tools, revision 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-the-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12), and 
[Invalid command line parameter when Android executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492676/invalid-command-line-parameter-when-android-execution) the solution to "invalid command line parameter when android execution" problem is adjusting the spaces in the path, but I don't know how.

I have Windows 7, Eclipse IDE for Parallel Application Developers with ADT Plugin.

The path to emulator.exe is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

Comment: Another possibility is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\`

Answer (score 6):

You have an option to change the SDK path. The SDK gets installed in C:\Program Files\Android by default. Now launch Eclipse -> Window-> Prefrences -> Android. Here you can browse to your android sdk location. I was successfully able to go through installation by doing this step and my sdk is installed in Program Files.

The above step is applicable to Android SDK version 15.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-installing, you can use the subst dos command to create a local drive alias.

```
Subst z: "c:\program files (x86)\android"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall Android SDK to shorter path with no spaces. I remember reading the Android SDK recommendation, where the path with spaces is described as wrongdoing.

You can not even have it there in Program Files in first place, because the installer (not zip, but recommended installer) picks the C:\AndroidSDK as suggested location.

I think there is no workaround for this other that reinstall

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it took me away from the whole Eclipse and programming dilemma. Instead of reinstalling few gigas once again, I just moved the installed files outside the Program Files (x86). So it's now C:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk\tools instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools.

Comment: Another recommendation from experience. Install Andriod Eclipse Plugin from Google update web site from inside Eclipse, but do it only AFTER you have Andriod-SDK already installed on machine.