# Android emulator r12 and MONO (invalid command-line parameter)

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android, android-2.2-froyo

I have run into the Android emulator r12 bug (As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-the-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492676/invalid-command-line-parameter-when-android-execution) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter)) but unfortunately moving the SDK location as described in the answers doesn't work.

If I change the directory location - the emulator starts working but - MONO will throw an exception (along the lines of "couldnt start emulator"). However leaving it where it is the emulator simply never starts and MONO will sit and wait.

Going into the AVD manager and attempting to start the emulator returns with the error.

```
invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
```

I am assuming if I can just get the AVG manager to start the emulator MONO will also start working again.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just move it, because Mono uses the registry key that the Android SDK installer wrote when it was installed to find it.  You need to uninstall the Android SDK and reinstall to a location without spaces in it.  (Or update the registry key to your new location.)

Comment: The other answers said you could "just move it" but clearly you are correct as reinstalling into the root directory did seem to fix the problem.